# NullPointerException on Handler Runnable function

Tags: android, handler, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to show progressive radar images on Google Maps via the presentation of sequential `GroundOverlay`s that use a preset array of radar images. To not make the user interface busy, I am using a different thread for this. Unfortunately, it seems that a weird `NullPointerException` is happening. I have debugged the code, and have not found any null variables that could be causing this.

What should I do?

I will only show the relevant code: (Note that radaroverlay, map, images, image_index and MAP_BOUNDS are global variables and are not null - see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7hP9.jpg)).

EDIT - Simplified the code below. Still gives the exact same errors.

```java
public void createLooper() {
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(run == true) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this,500);
            } else {
                return;
            }

            if(radaroverlay != null) {
                radaroverlay.remove();
            }
            // Problem happens in the line below.
            try {
                GroundOverlayOptions opts = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                                             .image(images[image_index])
                                             .positionFromBounds(MAP_BOUNDS)
                                             .transparency((float) 0.3);
                radaroverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(opts);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                run = false;
            }

            if(image_index == 19) {
                image_index = 0;
            } else {
                image_index++;
            }
        }
    };
    //mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

And corresponding `logcat`

```java
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at maps.z.aa.<init>(Unknown Source)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at maps.z.bi.a(Unknown Source)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at maps.z.bi.b(Unknown Source)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at maps.z.ag.addGroundOverlay(Unknown Source)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IGoogleMapDelegate.java:182)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:249)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addGroundOverlay(Unknown Source)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(Unknown Source)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at com.aquamet.saramap.MapActivity$2$1.run(MapActivity.java:520)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
02-27 16:58:04.815: E/AndroidRuntime(6791):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Debug:
[image: Debugged variables]

Comment: Hard to tell with just this code, but I would imagine when you set the map ground overlay, your image index may not be filled or go up to 19. Is it 20 items?

Comment: Also, if radaroverlay is not null do you want to remove it? Or do you want to just set it to null?

Comment: Well it's an animation, so I need to remove an overlay before adding a new one. Does that make sense?

Comment: And yes there is exactly 20 items.

Comment: @JaneDoh: I edited the post to show variable values at that line.

Comment: Ya, interesting. And map_index and MAP_BOUNDS are initialized?

Comment: @JaneDoh : Yes they are. Funny thing is, while debugging, I can create a GroundOverlay object with the exact same parameters successfully.

Comment: Have you tried separating the new GroundOverlay() line (to the line above it) of course assigning it to a new variable? Afterwards, test if you're getting an object or if it's returning null.

Comment: @DigCamara : I seperated the options from the addGroundOverlay function. Sure enough, opts is not null. One thing I should say is that radaroverlay is in fact null on the first run of the loop. Could this be causing the problem. I don't see why it would...

Comment: don't think so. How about MAP_BOUNDS, I see it's not null, but what values does it hold?

Comment: @DigCamara : Sorry for late answer, I had to go home. Anyways, it was a variable access problem in different threads. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well It turned out that the problem was that when I used a thread to update the GroundOverlays, while I could read from variables (if written by main thread before new thread is created, as is the case), I could not write to variables and expect the main thread to get the same result.

This explains why I could generate opts (read from `images`, `image_index` and `MAP_BOUND` ), but could not make the map set up a new GroundOverlay (write to `map` object).

I ended up using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) instead of thread, which takes care of concurrent variable problems.

Resulting code:

```java
public void createLooper() {
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(run == true) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this,500);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if(image_index == img_size) {
                image_index = 0;
            }
            if(radaroverlay != null) {
                radaroverlay.remove();
            }
            // Problem happens in the line below.
            try {
                GroundOverlayOptions opts = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                                             .image(images[image_index])
                                             .positionFromBounds(MAP_BOUNDS)
                                             .transparency((float) 0.3);
                radaroverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(opts);
                image_index++;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                run = false;
            }
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(runnable);
}
```